# How to format to timestamp with Luxon

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp, momentjs, luxon

I'm switching from moment to Luxon.
Currently, using moment I can can convert a `Date()` to timestamp format with this:

```
       ....moment()
      .subtract(2, 'hours')
      .utc()
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss [GMT]');
```

with the result looking like : `2022-12-01 17:40:16 GMT`

switching over to luxon and looking at the docs, I don't see any option to quite get me to that desired result. I've tried this:

```
const tryThis = date.minus({ hours: 2 }).toISO();
const getGMTIntheDate = DateTime.fromISO(tryThis);
const finalResult = getGMTIntheDate.toJSDate().toString();
```

which gives me this result: `Thu Dec 01 2022 09:49:44 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`

is there a custom formatting option or am I missing something in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this is what I was looking for

`date.toUTC().toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [datetimetoformat](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoformat). The formatting details are available [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens).

```
DateTime.now().toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss [GMT]')
```